# golang should this be an integration testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, integration-testing

I have a method which implements the a database interface, that method inserts an 'object' into the database.

```
type database interface {
    createLog(logDoc) (bool, error)
}


type mongo struct {
    database   string
    collection string
}

func (m mongo) createLog(l logDoc) (bool, error) {

    s, err := mgo.Dial("mongo")

    defer s.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

     err = s.DB(m.database).C(m.collection).Insert(l)
     if err != nil {
        return false, err
     }

     return true, nil
}
```

I want to be able to test the createLog method, how can I do this? should it be an integration test? if so what would be the your approach?

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam

Answer (score 0):

I just thought after watching the video & pondering this for a little bit and if nobody answered I would answer my own question.

This video resulted me in not writing any integration tests, rather writing unit tests. and creating stubs which allowed me to modify the way the interface behaved allowing me to tests when the database behaves correctly and incorrectly.

If you can think of a better way of describing what I said then please do :)